# Типичные ошибки программирования на Objective-C

Tags: ipad, cocoa, objective-c, ios, iphone

Расскажите общие ошибки, допущенные Objective-C разработчиками, которые вы знаете. Как мы можем их избежать? В общем, хотелось бы увидеть ошибки связанные с управлением памятью, анти-паттерны и любые другие ошибки программирования под iOS.

Пожалуйста, обоснуйте свой ответ, а также можно привести примеры.

Начну с одной известной ошибки. Это объявление нового класса без суперкласса, т.е. предполагая, что он будет иметь суперкласс по умолчанию. Здесь важно помнить, что **Objective-c не поддерживает множественное наследование, НО поддерживает несколько корней**. То есть корень - это не обязательно только класс NSObject. Таким образом, если вы пишете

```
/* не имеет суперкласса, не делайте этого! */
@interface MyClass
@end
```

Вы объявляете новый корень, а не подкласс NSObject.

Все подклассы NSObject должны быть прописаны вот так:

```
/* суперкласс NSObject */
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end
```

Comment: а эта фича, возможность иметь несколько рутов, вообще где-то используется? или только мешает?

Comment: @Angry Bird @Ленка что еще за "несколько корней", что вы понимаете под словом "корень"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. UIViews и UIViewControllers - разные вещи и не могут быть взаимозаменяемыми.
2. Не каждый контроллер должен быть UIViewController.
3. Жизненный цикл UIViewController. В частности вьюшка выгружается (unloaded) в ответ на  memory warnings. Обычно это бывает, когда разработчик использует вьюшку для хранения данных. Результат - потеря данных.

Answer (score 3):

Эта ошибка относится не только для новичков Objective-C (но и для Java, например). То есть проблема общего понимания того, что пишешь.

Сравнение через ==

```
str == @"Test"
```

Вместо

```
[str isEqualToString:@"Test"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Самая типичная ошибка - нахвататься верхушек, минуя стадию получения полноценных базовых знаний по языку и его обвязке. Остальное всего лишь следствие.

Comment: Минусы возможно ставят потому, что сам вопрос неформатный. Мы его раньше не замечали (таких много), а теперь закроем. В будущем – лучше не тратьте силы, отвечая на вопросы вроде "полный список всех ...". Тут вся метка [tag:objective-c] посвящена типичным ошибкам и собирать их в одном вопросе не стоило.

Comment: А вообще, я согласен, что корень ошибок — в непонимании основ.

Comment: Вы бы хоть как-нибудь конкретизировали. А то сейчас ваш ответ выглядит как «надо хорошо разбираться» — кто ж спорит?

Comment: Хорошо, конкретизирую: чтобы не возникали подобные ошибки, надо прочитать хотя бы первые 20 страниц любой книги по objc. Хотя бы. О большем просить уже как-то и неудобно. Остальные проблемы решаются в контексте конкретных вопросов и ответов, для чего, собственно, данный ресурс и предназначен.