# Что может подразумеваться под корнем класса?

Tags: objective-c, c++

В одном из вопросов на данном форуме увидел вот такое утверждение:
"Objective-c не поддерживает множественное наследование, НО поддерживает несколько корней."
Что подразумевается под словом корень? Речь идет о том, что любой класс может удовлетворять нескольким интерфейсам?

Ссылка на оригинальный вопрос:
[Типичные ошибки программирования на Objective-C](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1756/ios-%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации сказано, что "корень" в Objective-C один:

> When an Objective-C object needs to
> work with an instance of another
> class, it is expected that the other
> class offers certain basic
> characteristics and behavior. For this
> reason, Objective-C defines a root
> class from which the vast majority of
> other classes inherit, called
> NSObject. When one object encounters
> another object, it expects to be able
> to interact using at least the basic
> behavior defined by the NSObject class
> description.
>
> When you’re defining your own classes,
> you should at a minimum inherit from
> NSObject. In general, you should find
> a Cocoa or Cocoa Touch object that
> offers the closest functionality to
> what you need and inherit from that.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/DefiningClasses/DefiningClasses.html

Comment: > "корень" в Objective-C один  

Не совсем: есть ещё [NSProxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProxy_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Мне вот интересно, а зачем вообще делать универсальный базовый класс? Чтобы единообразно работать с классами "ложка", "формула" и "дельфин"? Вряд ли.

Comment: @smallFish: Из-за отсутствия шаблонов.

Например, что должно быть типом ключа `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @smallFish выделение памяти, реакация на посланные сообщения, KVO, message forwarding, etc. По сути NSObject это просто набор удобных обёрток над «голым» рантаймом Objective-C.   

Посмотреть пример реализации NSObject можно увидеть [здесь](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-01-25-lets-build-nsobject.html)

Comment: @VladD, @VioLet, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Корнем в данном случае называют класс, от которого унаследованы все остальные (частая ситуация, кстати, в дельфи почти все или даже все классы наследовались от TObject, в qt многие от QObject и т.п.), как верно заметили выше, их реально несколько. Скажу даже больше - это наследование от NSObject, строго говоря, не является даже свойством языка как такового - это свойство конкретной библиотеки Cocoa и родственных ей (хотя она, по большому счету, единственная пригодная для полноценной разработки), но принципиального запрета на создание классов-ненаследников вроде бы нет, только придется все alloc-dealloc самому писать. Причем даже Cocoa использует у себя как классы Objective-C, так и обычные сишные структуры (коими являются всяческие NSRect, NSPoint и т.п.).